# How to emit new structure

Tags: c#, .net, cil

```
var instanceType = typeof(T);            
LocalBuilder instanceBuilder = il.DeclareLocal(instanceType);// T 
if (instanceType.IsValueType)
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, instanceBuilder);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, instanceBuilder);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, instanceBuilder);
}
else
{
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, instanceType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, instanceBuilder);
}

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Test");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { TypeUtil._StringType }));

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, instanceBuilder);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { TypeUtil._ObjectType }));
```

Can anybody tell me how to emit new structure creation through it default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `ldloca` (or `ldflda` / `ldsflda`) and `initobj`. There is nothing to store (the `stloc_s` is unnecessary). The second parameter to `initobj` is the *type* token, not the address:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var method = new DynamicMethod("create", typeof(Foo), new[] { typeof(int) });
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        var local = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(Foo));

        // initialize the local (essentially: the default ctor)
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, typeof(Foo));

        // assign the parameter value to the property
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Foo).GetProperty(nameof(Foo.Id)).GetSetMethod());

        // load, box, and call CWL
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(Foo));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod(
            nameof(Console.WriteLine), new[] { typeof(object) }));

        // return the value of the 
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, local);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // call the emitted method
        var del = (Func<int, Foo>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, Foo>));
        var foo = del(42);
    }

}
public struct Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // not usually a good idea, note
    public override string ToString() => Id.ToString();
}
```

Comment: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, instanceBuilder);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Initobj, instanceType);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, instanceBuilder);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, instanceType);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { TypeUtil._ObjectType }));
                //il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, instanceBuilder);

Comment: @yjq and... what do you want me to make of that? it is unclear to me...

Comment: @yjq if you just want to box it and call CWL... I can add that to my code example (edit: done)

Comment: @yjq oh, I see - in your code in the comment, the problem is that you've used `ldloca` for the box, when you actually want `ldloc`. You box a value, not an address. It doesn't dereference. You should always refer to the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.box(v=vs.110).aspx - "1. A value type is pushed onto the stack." - not an address, a value type. Alternatively, the easiest way to write IL is to write what you want in C#, compile it, then look at the emitted IL via ILDASM or similar.

Comment: I recently learned about Emit and wanted to write a way to convert a Table into an entity. I failed when the entity was a value type. I now want to know how to create its default entity based on the type of entity passed, and WriteLine...Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Can you  add  your  code example?Thank you very much

Comment: I made a stretch of the party. Thank you very much

Comment: I made a stretch of the party. Thank you very much

Comment: @yjq I... already did add the code example, somewhere between 40 and 55 minutes ago...

Comment: Yes, I just got my network card. I didn't see it. Sorry

Comment: Sorry, I would like to ask another question, how to use emit to the structure of the property assignment, I tried but failed.

Comment: @yjq updates to show property assignment; note that this works differently between value-types and reference-types; with a value-type you load the **address** ("ldloca") and use **static call** ("call"); with a reference-type you load the *reference value* ("ldloc") and use **virtual call** ("callvirt"). Note you can also "mix it up" by doing "constrained call", but that's an *even more advanced* topic!

Comment: I have just changed Ldloc to Ldloca, and I have not really understood the difference between the two before, but now I understand. thank you very much

Comment: Or you could just be evil and rely on the CLR's stack-clearing behavior to guarantee local variables are zero instead of junk.  Then you won't need to call initobj at all - all you need to do is declare the variable and it's already constructed for you.  Of course, if they ever modify the stack clearing routine so it only covers places that can possibly hold references, then this would no longer be evil, it would just be stupid.

Comment: @MarcGravell - the only time I ever use constrained prefix in my own code is when I'm calling methods on a structure that the structure itself does not define (i.e., anything on System.Object and System.ValueType).  And I use callvirt in those cases.  Is there really a good use case for a constrained static call (other than, I assume, base class method calls)?

Comment: @hoodaticus absolutely: calling interface methods without boxing; that's the main use case of constrained call